# Can we change the height of tkinter menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, ttk

I am adding lots of options in the tkinter popup menu widget, but it fills the whole screen height (as shown in image).
I want to limit the number of displayed options in tkinter menu like the **tkinter combobox's listbox** height (which can be changed by passing the `height` parameter)

**Is there any way to do the same with menu widget? Please help!**

**Example:**

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Menu

# root window
root = Tk()

# create a menubar
menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

# create the file_menu
file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg="grey50", activebackground="blue")

# add lots of menu items to the File menu
for i in range(1,100):
    file_menu.add_command(label=i)

# add the File menu to the menubar
menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu",menu=file_menu)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You're creating a UI that will be very difficult for humans to use. You should consider a different method of providing these options to users. Nobody would enjoy working with a menu item dozens or  hundreds of items.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't want to give hundreds of options, but a popup menu with a **fixed height** having the up-down arrows to scroll through the option list.

Comment: When you create your menu try using `columnbreak=1` at appropriate places. This will turn a one dimensional list into a two dimensional panel.

Comment: It's impossible because ```tkinter.Menu```(and Tcl/Tk) uses the system menu component. Think about why all major OSs and GUI frameworks do not provide that feature. Just redesign your UI as Bryan said.

Comment: "a popup menu with a fixed height having the up-down arrows to scroll through the option list." - are you familiar with `ListBox`, and/or `ComboBox`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I am familiar with combobox. I actually want a right click popup window which have this scroll feature.